# Part of the image is hidden, without overflowing

Tags: css, image

I have some problem with putting logo in right place. Now I done it, but the image is not visible fully.
Example screen :http://gyazo.com/1d23c924cdb401fc0cca76b946e57dcb

There is no element that overflows that image. I tried to put in body, header or anywhere else than header but without any luck, It still shows like this. :(
css

```
#header{
width:1000px;
height:136px;
background:url(header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-position:0px 0px;
margin:auto;
}
#logo{
float:left;
padding:45px 0 0 15px;
}
```

Html

```
 <div id="logo"> <%= link_to image_tag('logo.png', :width => 400,:height=>80,:title => 'SIA Ecotechno'), root_path %></div>
```

Somebody can tip me for answer?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post some more code(html/css) and would you bother to make a fiddle?

Comment: Maybe the image is half drawed? :)

Comment: If it renders the same no matter where it is (body, header, etc.) probably it has to do with the image itself. Can you provide URL for that particular image?

Comment: @Morpheus Image it self is perfect.

Comment: @Igle I am using Ruby On Rails and all images ar stored on local system, so creating fiddle would be pain in ..But I will try.

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds, can you hover on the image's src attribute in Google Web Developer (see screenshot). Does the image load correctly when you hover it?

Comment: The `<a></a>` tag is messing around, maybe trying a fixed height on that one too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is from href, you should try to make it :

```
#logo a {
 display: block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

OR

```
#logo a {
 overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

I changed logo name to other than logo.png and it worked.
So I have somewhere duplicate logo.png file.

Tnx for all of you :)